# How to diagnose not working Reverse Proxy Server in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I have added a  section to httpd.conf for a reverse proxy server but nothing seems to happen.  Nothing is getting written to either the error or transfer logs.

Any suggestions on how to diagnose the fault?

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName www.domain.org.uk
  ServerAlias domain
  LogLevel Info
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain-error_log
  TransferLog /var/log/httpd/domain-access_log
  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://domain.org.uk/
    ProxyPassReverse http://domain.org.uk/
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: To diagnose the fault, you find the misconfigured lines in your configuration file(s). If you provide the relevant sections of your config, someone here may help.

Comment: What behavior are you seeing for requests that you think should be proxied?  Where is the `domain.org.uk` site hosted?  And what's the output from `apachectl -S`?

Comment: Make sure to restart Apache. It makes sense but we easily forget.

Comment: Have a look at [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directive, it will be useful to debug.